# How to create underlined titles of parts, sections,

Tags: formatting, titlesec

I'm using `titlesec` and I want to know if there is a way to make the titles with underline.

Comment: Yes of course. Could you give more details? Do you want  a rule below titles or really an underlined title? Centred? Left or right aligned?

Comment: @Bernard -  For you question: really an underlined title. Centred (but I want to know how can I change the direction if I want...). Thank you!!

Comment: I've forgotten: section or part numbers on the same line as the title?

Comment: @Bernard - Yes!

Comment: @Bernard - and one more thing if it's possible: If the name of the section is ZZZ (for example) - I want to know how to put symbol before the name and after it, e.g. aZZZa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
 \makeatletter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
 \usepackage{ntheorem}
 \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

  \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{soulutf8}%
 \setul{1ex}{1.5pt}
 \titleformat{\section}{\Large \bfseries \filcenter}{\ul{Section \thesection}}{1em}{\ul}
 \titleformat{name=\section, numberless}{\Large \bfseries \filcenter}{}{0em}{\ul}
 \usepackage{xunicode}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setdefaultlanguage{english}
%
 \setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

 \begin{document}

 \section*{Hello}
 \vskip1cm \section{A Numbered Hello}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

If you want titles to be `flushleft` use the directive `\taggedright`. To have a title ‘flushright’, use the directive `\raggedright`.

Comment: It's doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Could you post a short example code of what you've tried? By the way, sorry for   a typo in the proposed code: `\bfseries` has only one final `s`.

Comment: But I have Hebrew fonts, it's OK?

Comment: Here is the example: https://anotepad.com/notes/5jpfks

Comment: I've never had the opportunity to type in right-to-left languages, but I suppose you compile with `xelatex`?

Comment: Yes.... (But with pdflatex it also making problems :( )

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't obtain any pdf with your code, but as I don't have the fonts you mention maybe it's the reason. B.t.w., you copied the proposed code with errors.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don;t know what do... Can you put an example? That I will run it and I will see how it works? (.lyx file). I thought that you will tell me why there are errors at the code ;-)

Comment: I've posted a short code that works in english. See if you can make it work in Hebrew. Also, you'd better load `ntheorem`, which is more powerful than `theorem`

Comment: Still don't work :-( do you have any idea why? I have a problem with the `\ul` command (I'm not talking about your example, at your example it's give much more errors :-(  ).

Comment: BTW - why the theorem package is matter here?

Comment: It's work at English but not at Hebrew - this what I get: https://imgur.com/ygn9G7F - do you now why?

Comment: I accept your answer because I didn't mention nothing about Hebrew ;-)